# Is the following Hasse diagram for a partial order correct?

Tags: relations

I'm not sure if my Hasse diagram is correct for the partial order $$R = \{(2,2),(4,2),(6,2),(6,3),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)\}.$$ Any confirmation/correction would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.${}{}{}{}{}$